# Flask Babelex 0.9.4 and % escaping

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-babel

In a `Flask` application we recently upgraded `Werkzeug` to 1.0.1 (so we could set the same site on cookies), which forced a few dependencies, among which `Flask-BabelEx==0.9.4`.

After this upgrade, the handling of escaped % (percent signs) changed in a very troubling way.  Where `gettext('foo %%')` used to return `*"foo %"*`, it now returns `*"foo %%"*`, in other words, the escaping of % sign seems to not be handled.  I thought, ok, a little upward incompatibility, we just have to replace all the `%%` by `%` in babel strings (in reference language as well as in all translations, so that's a big deal already).

But that's not the end of the story, because for all babel strings used *within Jinja2 templates*, such as `{{ _("This is a percent sign: %") }}`, the escaping of `%` signs is still handled, so this still needs to be  `{{ _("This is a percent sign: %%") }}`.   So do we have to handle both `%`-escaped and unescaped babel strings depending on where they are used?  Is there a setting somewhere that would alleviate this escaping issue.